# How many watts are actually going through the resistive heating wire vs. lost to the rest of the circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I'm doing some experiments with resistive heating.

I have a variable-output power supply where I can set a constant voltage or a constant amperage.

I cut a small length of nichrome wire (12.3cm with diameter 0.5mm). If I hook everything up and set the output to 1.00V, the current is 1.365A meaning I get 1.365 W of output.

My question is, how many of these W are actually going through the wire itself -- and therefore contributing to its increase in temperature? How could I determine this?

My attempt so far: the way everything is hooked up is that the ends of the wire are clipped to the power supply with alligator clips. If I instead connect the alligator clips directly to each other then I get these values, from which I calculated the resistance for that arrangement:

```
0.01 V , 0.133 A -- 0.07519 ohms
0.02 V , 0.322 A -- 0.06211 ohms
0.03 V , 0.508 A -- 0.05906 ohms
0.04 V , 0.694 A -- 0.05764 ohms
0.05 V , 0.886 A -- 0.05643 ohms
0.06 V , 1.365 A -- 0.04395 ohms
0.10 V , 1.771 A -- 0.05647 ohms
0.20 V , 3.562 A -- 0.05615 ohms
0.25 V , 4.442 A -- 0.05628 ohms
```

From this it seems safe to say the resistance of the circuit approaches 0.056 ohms at higher voltages -- though I'm not sure why it varies across different voltage levels.

Whereas with the full circuit, the values are:

```
1.00 V , 1.365 A -- 0.73260 ohms
```

So I made these attempts to calculate it:

1. If I subtract the resistance of the clips together from the resistance of the full circuit, I get 0.67632 ohms. To get the same 1.365 A would require only 0.923 V instead of 1.00 V . (1.00 V - 0.923 V) * 1.365 A is **0.105105 W** . Therefore this is the amount of W needed -- in terms of extra voltage -- to run the circuit at the given current level.
2. If I look just at the clips together, it took 0.06 V to get the same 1.365 A of current, or **0.0819 W**. Therefore this is the amount of W that's being 'lost' to the rest of the circuit .
3. According to [mwswire.com](https://mwswire.com/resistance-wire-2/#:%7E:text=Nichrome%2C%20a%20non%2Dmagnetic%2080,to%20oxidation%20at%20high%20temperatures.) , the resistance of nichrome wire is 675 ohm-cmil/ft . The length is 12.3cm = 0.4035433 ft. The diameter is 0.5mm meaning the circular area of the cross-section is 0.19635 mm^2 = 387.5 cmils. Therefore 675 / 387.5 * 0.4 = 0.702946 ohms is the calculated resistivity, so with a current of 1.365 A we get 1.3097 W going through the wire. Therefore the difference of 1.365 W - 1.3097W = **0.0553 W** is the answer.

   I'm not very certain of this one though as it depends on theoretical/calculated/posted values as opposed to the observed ones. I would prefer an answer that I can measurably observe.

Is one of these the right answer, or is it something else?

Comment: What I see is that you have 3 values that are quite close to each other.

Comment: Consider learning about 3 and 4 wire resistance measurements. Using multiple wires and testing the total resistance in different directions allows you to isolate the resistance of one particular resistor. This is how resistances are measured accurately and without errors from connections and leads.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_3.html , if you have resistors in sequence the total resistance is the sum of the individual resistances.

Further, given a certain current, the same current flows through all resistors.

So in the given circuit, we have 1.365A of current. We know the total resistance of everything but the nichrome wire is 0.056 ohms, and the total resistance of the circuit is 0.733 ohms. Therefore the resistance of just the wire is 0.677 ohms.

This means 0.677*1.365 = 0.924 V are going across the nichrome wire.

And therefore, 0.924 V * 1.365 A = 1.261 W of power are going through it.

And the difference — 0.104 W - is what is ‘lost’ to the rest of the circuit.

So, #1 is correct.

---

As an aside, the 0.677 ohms corresponds to an 11.84cm wire with the same specifications (assuming the [675 ohm*cmil/ft figure](https://mwswire.com/resistance-wire-2/#:%7E:text=Nichrome%2C%20a%20non%2Dmagnetic%2080,to%20oxidation%20at%20high%20temperatures.) is correct) -- the extra 0.46cm figure looks about right as I'm clipping the wire not all the way at the end. So it all adds up.